# Zend2: how to render view wrapped in layout into a variable?

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to save all rendered content (layout + view) in a variable to save it with Zend_Cache, *I can't use Varnish, nginx or other software to do so*. Currently I'm doing it like that:

```
$view->setTemplate('application/index/index');
$viewContent = $renderer->render($view);
$view = $this->getEvent()->getViewModel();
$view->content = $viewContent;
$content = $renderer->render($view);
```

Can anyone suggest me more elegant solution? Mb catching native **render** event with EventManager or some tricks with Response object or **dispatch** event? Would like to hear all suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two listeners to your `Module` class. one listener checks early, just after `route` if the match is one that's cached. The second listener waits for `render` and grabs the output to store it in cache:

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        // A list of routes to be cached
        $routes = array('foo/bar', 'foo/baz');

        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $em  = $app->getEventManager();
        $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

        $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($sm) {
            $route = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
            $cache = $sm->get('cache-service');
            $key   = 'route-cache-' . $route;

            if ($cache->hasItem($key)) {
                // Handle response
                $content  = $cache->getItem($key);

                $response = $e->getResponse();
                $response->setContent($content);

                return $response;
            }
        }, -1000); // Low, then routing has happened

        $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function($e) use ($sm, $routes) {
            $route = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
            if (!in_array($route, $routes)) {
                return;
            }

            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $content  = $response->getContent();

            $cache = $sm->get('cache-service');
            $key   = 'route-cache-' . $route;
            $cache->setItem($key, $content);
        }, -1000); // Late, then rendering has happened
    }
}
```

Just make sure you register a cache instance under `cache-service` in the service manager. You can update above example to check during the render event if the route is in the `$routes` array. Now you just check if the cache has the key, which might be slower than doing `in_array($route, $routes)` like during the `render` event.